# Can I be sure that the name of a Linux Audit record's field is unique?

Tags: linux, security, logs, audit, linux-audit

I am creating a parser/converter from the Linux Audit format. As I was studying the format, looking at examples and reading the documentation I stumbled upon a problem.

---

Can I be sure that the field names inside a single record are **unique**?

For example, is a record like this one is legal / appear in real world implementations:

> ```
> type=TYPE msg=audit(1.002:3): msg="the first msg field" msg="the second msg field"
> ```

---

The second related question is whether I can there are there will be only one `pid` in an event? For example, is this event is legal / appear in real world implementations:

> ```
> type=TYPE1 msg=audit(1.002:3): pid=0 msg="texthere"
> type=TYPE2 msg=audit(1.002:3): pid=0 msg="differenttexthere"
> ```

Comment: I see you created the tag [tag:linux-audit]. That's meant to be a synonym of [tag:auditd], right?

Comment: @Gilles, I am not sure about it. I see `auditd` as the userspace daemon mostly. Linux Audit is a much wider tag which might include questions about the standard itself. I am working a lot with the Linux Audit format documentation lately and I've been missing a proper tag for my questions. `audit` seems to be too general and `auditd` is not really the tag I need. This is why I decided to create the `linux-audit` tag.

Comment: [tag:auditd] wasn't used specifically about the daemon, it was about the whole framework (`auditd`, `auditctl` and other related tools). Is there a difference between the Linux audit framework and the Linux audit standard? Please chime in on the [meta thread](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/auditing-the-audit-and-auditd-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Steve Grubb's reply on the official mailing list ([link to the email](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-July/msg00067.html)):

### Steve's answer:

> > Is it possible that there are duplicate fields in a record?
>
> Sometimes. I've tried to fix those when it happens. The problem is
>   that not  everyone runs their audit code by this mail list so that we
>   can check it to  see that its well formed. What I am planning to do is
>   write an audit event  validation suite that checks that events are
>   well formed and that expected  events are being written when they are
>   supposed to and in the order that they  are supoosed to. Cleaning up
>   these events is high on my TODO list.
>
> > Something
> >     like (which doesn’t make much sense obviously):
> >
> > ```
> >     type=CWD msg=audit(1464013682.961:409):  cwd="/root” cwd=“/usr”
> > ```
>
> Something like this will not happen, its more likely around auid and
>   uid. The  reason being that the kernel adds somethings automatically
>   because its a  trusted source of information. User space can write
>   contradictory information.  For example if a daemon is working on
>   behalf of a user but its auid has not  been set for the user, then you
>   might see this.

### tl;dr

It is possible however it is uncommon and discouraged.